# In Python (2.7.3), how do I stop and relaunch a process without breaking a loop?

Tags: python, timer, subprocess, interrupt

I feel like my title doesn't use the correct terminology to describe my problem, but I'm not sure how else to describe it. I'm using BioPython to interface with the built-in PAML programs, in particular the run() method from codeml. Occasionally the calculations in run() fail to converge for certain input data, which means that my script just waits indefinitely for a response from run() that never comes. I find that usually if I stop and re-start run() it will converge on the second or third try. So my question is, is it possible to implement some sort of timer in the script such that after a certain amount of time the script will stop the run() process and re-start it?

I'm not sure including my current script is relevant, but I will in case it is at all helpful.

Thanks!

```
for infile in PAMLinfiles:
processing += 1
ensemid = infile.split("_")[0]
print "Processing " + ensemid + " (" + str(processing) + " of " + str(numfiles) + ")" + "\t" + str((time.time() - start)/60) + " minutes elapsed."
TotRes[ensemid]= {}
TotRes[ensemid]["Null"] = {}
TotRes[ensemid]["So"] = {}
cml.alignment = PAMLinDir + infile
cml.tree = TagTreeDir + "RAxML_bestTree." + ensemid #infile.split("_")[0]
for n in range(0, 2):
    cml.out_file = "CMLR_" + models[n] + "_" + ensemid #infile.split("_")[0]
    cml.set_options(fix_omega = n)
    cml.set_options(omega = 1)
    results = cml.run()  ###This is the process that sometimes stalls out
    TotRes[ensemid][models[n]]["lnL"] = results['NSsites'][2]['lnL']
#.....
#and on and on with lots of other lines of code
```

Comment: Which OS? On Linux/Mac OS/Unix that is feasible using the "signal"  internal library. On Windows you will have to resort to threads, and having one thread to check the time the call to "run" is taking.

Comment: I run these scripts on Linux clusters with 16 threads. I generally try to have one script running on each thread so as not to waste computational resources but I suppose I could scale that back if I need additional threads to watch the timer.... Hrm.

Comment: The "signal" internal library should work them - to check for timeouts. I will try to elaborate some example code bellow.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the signal library. I've been trying to read up on it on other stackoverflow threads, but the sense I get is that if you are utilizing multiple threads, you never know which thread is going to get the "signal." Is that correct? Essentially I am launching multiple python scripts on a 16 core node... so if one of the scripts on one of the threads sends the signal, is it possible that another thread would catch the signal?

Comment: hmm..yes.  So, if you are already multi-threaded, the way to go is to have on special "sentinel" thread, tthat would take care of the timeouts.

Comment: Do you have any suggested reading on how to go about implementing that? I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Thanks!